# Can anyone identify this language for me?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm inheriting some code from a third-party system.  The vendor will supply me with their documentation, but if their language is some variant of a more general language then it would be useful to know.  A couple of snippets are below:

```
 for var i = 0 to short_q.getSize()-1 
 { 
    sumq+=short_q[i];
    sumpq+=short_q[i]*short_p[i];
 } 

 Number trd_qty_short := trd_qty_short1 + trd_qty_short2;
```

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7652/identifying-programming-languages-by-a-piece-of-code

Comment: other than the for without parenthesis and the assignment in declaration :=, there is nothing very defining about this code. Do you have more?

Comment: Some more snips:

    Vector<Number> short_p = new Vector<Number>();

    while exec_iter.hasElem() { var currentExec = exec_iter.getElemMoveNext();

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SourceClassifier](https://github.com/chrislo/sourceclassifier):

> Source classifier identifies programming language using a Bayesian
>   classifier trained on a corpus generated from the Computer Language
>   Benchmarks Game . It is written in Ruby and availabe as a gem. To
>   train the classifier to identify new languages download the sources
>   from github.
>
> Out of the box SourceClassifier recognises Css, C, Java, Javascript,
>   Perl, Php, Python and Ruby.